# Microsoft Owin Sign-Out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Microsoft.Owin to build Sign-On Application integrated with many other applications.

As summary, I generate an accessToken for every application try to login. the application verify accessToken and sign in successfully.

Code sample:

```
 var identity = UserService.UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);

AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());

var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;

ticket.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

var dataProtectionProvider = new EFileDataProtectionProvider(client.ClientID, client.ClientSecret);
var accessTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtectionProvider);

Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;

string accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);


return accessToken;
```

**The problem is:
How to force all other applications to sign out when a user signed out from one application ???**

Comment: what do you mean by *all other applications*

Comment: Any application try to authenticate through my application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you are trying to logout all the other devices once one device is logged in thus making only one user on the account at all times.

What you need to do is update your user security stamp like so :

```
  await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
```

and then the asp.identity validation will take care of the rest
Please note to have the validation enabled with "OnValidateIdentity" like so:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

This will check stamp validation every 60 seconds on every device.

Comment: Thanks dear, The main problem is that other devices(applications) have their own authentication and did not use the Owin security.

Comment: So make them use owin security(asp identity) next time they try to access it.